# hook_image_effect_info_alter() doesn't change effect callback

Tags: 7, media

I'm trying to patch the image effect from the [Kraken module](https://www.drupal.org/project/kraken).
I'm doing so by using [hook_image_effect_info_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21image%21image.api.php/function/hook_image_effect_info_alter/7.x) to point the 'effect callback' to my patched function, like this:

```
function patch_image_effect_info_alter(&$effects) {
  $effects['kraken_optimize']['effect callback'] = 'patch_kraken_optimize';
  watchdog('patch_kraken', print_r($effects, TRUE)); // logging for debug
}
```

The problem is that this the hook doesn't seem to really change the effect defined on the Kraken module. Even though I'm getting the log message I defined in the hook with the updated *effect callback*, the original Kraken module effect is still being applied.

Am I using this hook the right way?

Comment: you are using the hook correctly ... are you certain that your callback isnt being called? Have you cleared cache?

Comment: @bleen my callback it is not being called, I set watchdogs on my callback and the original one to check. I also cleared the caches.
It seems that when the effect is applied the original definitions are restored somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.

It turns out there was another custom module "restoring" the original callback.